# Blazor Server App or React for Interactive Web UI

Tags: asp.net-core, react-redux, blazor-server-side

Please I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project that I need to develop a front-end UI to consume it, taking advantage of the Single Page Application (SPA) and component model of Blazor, I am thinking of using Blazor Server app, but my application is going to be an enterprise app with at least 20,000 concurrent users or more in the future and my concern is obviously the SignalR connection.

I know React also uses the SPA and component model approach.
Am at a fix as to which one to choose and whether it can be scalable in the future.
Thank you for your kind response.